# Remove SKU from the email

Tags: email, sku

I want to remove SKU from all email to customer

1) I create folder and copy file to not edit core

/app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/template/email/order/items.phtml

2) Delete this code

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
```

but Sku is still showing on email

What should I do..?

Comment: which email did  you test? you have to remove it from all the items.phtml files for it to be gone from all the emails (so also from email/order/invoice/items.phtml , email/order/creditmemo/items.phtml etc). also did you clear cache?

Comment: @Anja Wow Thanks to your advice I made it without core edit Thanks a lot! Have a good day! :)

Comment: In case you're using an extension that overrides emails, as in my case, I'm using Delivery Time extension. So the file I need to edit is at: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/magecheckout/deliverytime/order/email.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it from email/order/items.phtml from the `<thead>`.
Btw it's better practice to rewrite those files in your custom theme rather than changing core/base magento files, in case you want to upgrade your magento to a new version in the future.

Comment: Thanks! As you said, when I remove <thead> , all the lines are command out (Item,qty,) Is it okay? Please check my update question

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, but you just need to remove the <th> line which has <?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?>. your screenshot looks ok